# Symfony 2 and facebook login error

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I am using *fos_facebook* bundle to integrate *facebook* login system with my web app. I am getting following error.

> "The Facebook user could not be retrieved from the session"

Has anyone come across this problem? Could anyone successfully integrate facebook with symfony? Please provide your configuration  and userInterface class.

Comment: Why wouldn't you provide us your configuration and code examples?

Comment: the issue is solved please check: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/issues/59

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the browser a little time to handle the Facebook cookie.

```
<script>
   function goLogIn(){
       window.location = "{{ path('_security_check') }}";
   }

   function onFbInit() {
       if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null ) {
           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
              setTimeout(goLogIn, 500);
           });
       }
   }
</script>
```

this is a snip from the FOSFacebookBundle documentation. Where the proces is described :)

Comment: Usually, if if you are giving something an arbitrary delay of some sort, there is an underlying problem (emphasis on *usually*). Callbacks are a much better way to go. JavaScript is full of callback functionality.

Comment: Another thing with arbitrary delays is that because in this case the specifications of the machine executing your code is essentially unknown (you only know it has the ability to parse JS), then this half a second delay might not be enough! Even **worse** it might be **too much**! :)

Comment: @Lix -- I agree with your *usually* comment, but I'm not sure if the FB interface supports the callback.  Based on what I know, I fear this may be the best solution.